# Could psutil used with android operating systems

Tags: android, performance, networking, statistics

Could I use psutil in python to measure how much data is being transferred on my network interfaces for an android device?
If no is there any alternative for this for android devices?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [iPerf3 for Android](https://iperf.fr/iperf-download.php).

*iPerf3* has been ported to various platforms and is quite a versatile tool for network performance analysis.

An [iPerf3 Python wrapper](https://iperf3-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is available to call *iPerf3* functionality from Python code.

Comment: Thank you for your help,but I am trying to do an app to measure speed and consumption of my android device using python,but I do not know the best libraries to use